# Can I close the CMD window that opened with subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I have a program that need to run small tasks in new CMDs.
For example:

```
def main()
    some code
    ...
    proc = subprocess.Popen("start.bat")
    some code...
    proc.kill()
```

subprocess,Popen opens a new cmd window and runs "start.bat" in it.
proc.kill() kills the process but doesn't close the cmd window.
Is there a way to close this cmd window?

I thought about naming the opened cmd window so i can kill it with the command:

```
/taskkill /f /im cmdName.exe
```

Is it possible ?if no, What do you suggest ?

Edit, Added Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

a.py:

```
import subprocess,time
proc = subprocess.Popen("c.bat",creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
time.sleep(5)
proc.kill()
```

b.py

```
while True:
    print("IN")
```

c.bat

```
python b.py
```

Comment: Why not just run the script with a hidden CMD?

Comment: because the CMD will stay alive in backgroud.
If the main() will be executed 100 times then i'll have them all idle in the task manger .

Comment: cannot reproduce, even if the script has a `pause` in it, python closes the window when killing. Maybe try a [mcve] providing a sample .bat file with the problem, and how you're running your python program. Because python is running in a console, that doesn't open a new console. Only with pythonw it does (and successfully closes it)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre try to run in the subprocess a script that doesn't stop

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you can try the example i added

Comment: will do that in a moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's expected when a subprocess is running. You're just killing the `.bat` process.

You can use `psutil` (third party, use `pip install psutil` to install) to compute the child processes & kill them, like this:

```
import subprocess,time,psutil
proc = subprocess.Popen("c.bat",creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
time.sleep(5)

pobj = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
# list children & kill them
for c in pobj.children(recursive=True):
    c.kill()
pobj.kill()
```

tested with your example, the window closes after 5 seconds

Answer (score 4):

here is another way you can do it

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
command ='cmd'
prog_start=Popen(command,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
pidvalue=prog_start.pid
#this will kill the invoked terminal
subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /T /PID %i' % pidvalue)
```

Comment: Did not get it!! This closes the invoked cmd prompt(multiple as well)..tried myself.

Comment: my bad. you didn't explain that the `/T` option kills children as well. That'll work. nice. I'd use `check_call` for the taskkill command, though.

Comment: Will check that